# Python Module Reloading on WebSocket Remote Receive

Tags: python, file, websocket, python-importlib

I am trying to write a python web socket client which can receive user generated scripts & execute them.

My code looks like this so far:

```
import config
import websocket
import time, ssl, json, importlib, sys
#when putting "import script" here def main is found, but not reloaded later on

script_loaded = False

def import_script(ws): #import/reload script module
    global script_loaded
    global script
    try:
        if script_loaded:
            importlib.reload(script)
        else:
            import script
            script_loaded = True
    except Exception as e:
        iot.report_error(ws, 'Loading Script', str(sys.exc_info()[0]), str(e))
        print('Error: ' + str(sys.exc_info()[0]) + ': ' + str(e))

class iot:
    def report_error(ws, place, etype, error):
        msg = json.dumps({"context": 3, "place": place, "type": etype, "error": error}, sort_keys=True)
        ws.send(msg)
    def write(ws, socket, data):
        msg = json.dumps({"context": 2, "socket": socket, "data": data}, sort_keys=True)
        ws.send(msg)
    def display(data):
        print(data)
    def start(ws): #start script module (def main)
        try:
            script.main(ws)
        except Exception as e:
            iot.report_error(ws, 'Executing Script (main())', str(sys.exc_info()[0]), str(e))
            print('Error: ' + str(sys.exc_info()[0]) + ': ' + str(e))


connectionEstablished = False
def on_message(ws, message):
    global connectionEstablished
    global script_loaded
    global script
    try:
        decoded_data = json.loads(message)
        if decoded_data['context'] == 0: #Log on
            connectionEstablished = True
        elif decoded_data['context'] == 1: #Receive Script
            if connectionEstablished:
                file = open('script.py','w')
                file.write("from iot_daemon import iot\n\n")
                file.write(decoded_data['script']) #write received script to file (works)
                import_script(ws) #import/reload script
                if script_loaded:
                    iot.start(ws) #start script module (def main)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to process string: ' + str(e))

def on_error(ws, error):
    print('WebSocket Error: ' + error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("Closed.")

def on_open(ws):
    print("Connected.")
    msg = json.dumps({"context": 0, "type": 0, "key": config.key}, sort_keys=True)
    ws.send(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        if config.debugMode:
            websocket.enableTrace(True)
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(config.serverURL,
                                  on_message = on_message,
                                  on_error = on_error,
                                  on_close = on_close)
        ws.on_open = on_open
        ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Reconnecting...")
```

While receiving the script seems to work (script.py is updated when having a look at with a text editor), somehow reloading and executing the new version does not (it always runs the script version existing when the client is re-/started or it does not run the script at all if the import statement at the top of the script is left out).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually was quite a simple one: Python is not able to reload a module which at the moment is opened as a FileObject. So simply adding a "file.close()" solved it.